# Why is the total length of Introns greater than the total length of exons?

Tags: molecular-genetics, gene-expression, human-genetics

I have just been reading that typically the total length of the Exons of a split gene is very much smaller than to total number of its Introns.
Could anyone please explain why this is the case if its correct, why are some genes composed of more non coding DNA(intron) than coding DNA.
Thanks

Comment: `[..] if [it is] correct [..]` Yes it is correct. Please note that a gene is made of other things than just introns and exons (see [wiki > gene # structure_and_function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene#Structure_and_function)).